# How to properly reference nested field within an array within an aggregate framework (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in the following format:

```
Collection name: COLL1

{
    _id: "a",
    list: [
      {
         _id: "a1",
         ranking: 10
      },
      {
         _id: "a2",
         ranking: 30
      }
      ...
    ]

}

{
    _id: "b",
    list: [
      {
         _id: "b1",
         ranking: 10
      },
      {
         _id: "b2",
         ranking: 30
      }
      ...
    ]

}
```

When I call: `db.getCollection('COLL1').find({"_id": "a","list._id": "a1"});` I can see the results. However, if I call:

```
db.getCollection('COLL1').aggregate([
{ $match:
    { $expr:
        { $and: 
                    [
                        { $eq: ["$_id", "a"] },
                        { $eq: ["$list._id", "a1"] }
                    ]
        }
    }
}
])
```

Then nothing is returned. Does anyone know why? I think the issue is `{ $eq: ["$list._id", "a1"] }` but I'm not sure what exactly happened here.

I'm trying to get the complete document:

```
{
    _id: "a",
    list: [
      {
         _id: "a1",
         ranking: 10
      },
      {
         _id: "a2",
         ranking: 30
      }
      ...
    ]

}
```

This is part of my `aggregate`  syntax within a `$lookup` stage, so I have to use `aggregate([])` instead of `find()`. What I'm actually trying to achieve is the following:

```
...previous stages
{
        $lookup:{
            from: "COLL1",
            let: { local_id: "$_id" }, // this '$_id' is from another collection, not COLL1.
            pipeline: [
                { $match:
                    { $expr:
                        { $and:
                            [
                                { $eq: [ "$_id",  "a"] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$local_id", "$list._id" ] } // this is where I got in trouble.
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "matched_result"
        }
    },
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the second `$eq` with `$in` will work just fine. :)

```
db.getCollection('COLL1').aggregate([
{ $match:
    { $expr:
        { $and: 
                    [
                        { $eq: ["$_id", "a"] },
                        { $in: ["a1", "$list._id"] }
                    ]
        }
    }
}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need variables from previous pipeline stages, you can just use the same syntax as `.find()` inside `$match`

```
db.getCollection('COLL1').aggregate([
  { $match: { "_id": "a", "list._id": "a1" } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am implementing the `$match` within the `pipeline` within a `$lookup` stage. So I think I have to use `$expr`.

Comment: Then it would be great to mention this in your answer as well for other people that come across similar implementations.

Comment: I have updated more information. Hope this will help more people.